# How to retrieve data elements of an object when it refrences another object?

Tags: object, properties, reference

How can I access the elements from the object obj in this example?

```
class Shapes
{
  int shapeid;
  string name;
}

Shapes shape = new Shape();
shape.shapeid = 10;
shape.name = "roger";

object obj = shape;
```

How can I access obj.shapeid and obj.name??? This is just a hypothetical example. In real scenario I call a webservice method with a proxy, which return a object. I want to browse through the object to see the data with in. When I debug in VS, I see the data and child objects within but not sure how to get them programatically?

Comment: I'm not sure what is the language for your example but i ques you can get object properties the same way you set it.  
So if you set property: shape.shapeid = 10;
then you get property: newVariable = shape.shapeid;

Comment: I mean, when the shape object is assigned or passed to a variable of object type, how can I access the elements of shape object stored in object type variable?